# Why does BeautifulSoup.find not work when using a for loop?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, timeout, sleep, except

I am iterating through a list of URL's to extract 5 items from each URL using BeautifulSoup.find. The list contains about 2000 URL's. Because not every webpage is guaranteed to have all 5 items, I used try and except appropriately.

After completing the loop, I noticed 3 things:

1. The very first 5-10 links would run seamlessly meaning I would successfully retrieve all 5 items (none of the except blocks were used).
2. The overwhelming majority of URL's try blocks did not execute, and therefore it ran the except block for each item.
3. Everyone once in a while, a URL's try blocks **DID** execute and I would successfully retrieve all 5 items.

I placed the results in a list of dictionaries, and then created a dataframe.

```
cleanserlist = []
for link in productlinks:
    
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=3.05)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        print("Timeout occurred")
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    
    try:
        price = soup.find('span', class_="sellingPrice").text.strip()
    except:
        price = 'no price'
    try:
        name = soup.find('h1', class_='flex flex-xs-100').text.strip()
    except:
        name = 'no name'
    try: 
        ingredients = soup.find('div', class_='v-pane-content').text.strip()
    except:
        ingredients = 'no ingredients'
    try:
        rating = soup.find('div', class_='ratingValue').text.strip()
    except:
        rating = 'no rating'
    try:
        reviews = soup.find('span', class_='reviewCount').text.strip()
    except:
        reviews = 'no reviews'
    
    cleanser = {
        'name': name,
        'price': price,
        'rating': rating,
        'reviews' : reviews,
        'ingredients': ingredients
    }
    cleanserlist.append(cleanser)
    sleep(randint(1,3))
```

[image of first 44 rows of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaSqo.png)

[image of subsequent 44 rows of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcEp8.png)

Comment: Have you noticed that when (if?) a timeout occurs you still try to extract the response content?

Comment: Yes! It still runs after I get a timeout

Comment: What do you think will be in *r.content* if a timeout occurs? Also, why the *sleep()*? You have ~2,000 URLs to process so that will add at least 2,000 seconds to the overall processing time. Have you considered multithreading?

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if a timeout occurs. The sleep() is to control the crawl rate and basically mimic human behavior. I'm not familiar with multithreading Is that a potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

A "table driven" approach is highly appropriate for this kind of thing and makes for easier extensibility.

Given that there are a large number of URLs to [try to] access then a multithreaded approach is highly desirable for potentially greatly improved performance.

Here's an example of that kind of approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

CONTROL = [('price', 'span', 'sellingPrice'),
           ('name', 'h1', 'flex flex-xs-100'),
           ('ingredients', 'div', 'v-pane-content'),
           ('rating', 'div', 'ratingValue'),
           ('reviews', 'span', 'reviewCount')
           ]
AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'
TIMEOUT = 3.05
cleanserlist = []
productlinks = [] # list of URLs

headers = {'User-Agent': AGENT} # potentially more complex

def process(link):
    try:
        (r := requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=TIMEOUT)).raise_for_status()
        cleanser = {}
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        for v, e, c in CONTROL:
            try:
                cleanser[v] = soup.find(e, class_=c).text.strip()
            except Exception:
                cleanser[v] = f'no {v}'
        cleanserlist.append(cleanser)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error processing {link} due to {e}')


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process, productlinks)
    print(cleanserlist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the new insight. I tried your method and it returned an empty list. I modified some of your code because I got some syntax errors. [your approach example](https://imgur.com/a/DJkuP2t)

Comment: @itsanhtuanho There are no syntax errors in the code shown in this answer unless you're using an out-of-date version of Python (pre-3.8)

Comment: After upgrading python versions, the code ran, but I got plenty of 429 error codes due to too many requests for url. Should I include a sleep somewhere within the function to bypass this? [error code](https://imgur.com/a/SJhEcFp)

Comment: @itsanhtuanho Adding a sleep when the status is HTTP 429 *may* help but you might get better results by using a proxy pool. You should also look into retry mechanisms